# Como asociar latitud y longitud de ubicacion en una cuenta de usuario logueada con firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, studio

que tal, como están?, espero que bien, bueno mi consulta es la siguiente, logre cargar en la base de datos de firebase latitud y longitud mediante la ubicación en android studio, mi pregunta es como puedo subir este dato específicamente en la cuenta que esta hecho el login.

Explico la app:

Activity principal: Botón de Login y Registro.

Al seleccionar uno de estos botones te hará el login o te registrara en la app.

A continuación, ya registrado o logueado en la app, te llevara a la portada de la misma y en ese momento se guardara tu ubicación (latitud y longitud) habiendo otorgado el permiso anteriormente.

**Mi pregunta es:** ¿Como hago para que la latitud y longitud obtenidas se carguen en la cuenta de usuario que esta hecho el login?

Muchas gracias de antemano y cordial saludo buenas vibras.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: cuando de logeas deberias generar un usuario en la base de datos en tiempo real y luego con el id de usuario acceder y agregar los datos de latitud y longitud